# Regular expression to match German number

Tags: regex, formatting, cultureinfo

I am wondering, how would regular expression for testing correct format of number for German culture would look like.

In German, comma is used as decimal mark and dot is used to separate thousands.

Therefore:

- 1.000 equals to 1000
- 1,000 equals to 1
- 1.000,89 equals to 1000.89
- 1.000.123.456,89 equals to 1000123456.89

The real trick, seems to me, is to make sure, that there could be several dots, optionally followed by comma separator

Comment: Are you trying to restrict that only correct German input is allowed? Or are you simply trying to convert whatever the user put in to a "normal" number? (and in your last example I think you mean _1000123456.89_, it still has a comma there)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in last example (corrected). I am only trying to limit user from inserting invalid input.

Comment: Sometimes the best way to validate numbers is to use your language/framework's culture-sensitive parsing methods. In .NET, this would be [float.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh4863by(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Parsing numbers I can handle, but I want to restrict user from inserting strings, which could not be parsed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the regex I would use:

```
^-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OoeEW3N212EGh99K)

And this is a code example to interpret it as a valid floating point (notice the `parseFloat()` after the string replacements).

**Edit:** as mentioned in Severin Klug's answer, the below code assumes that the numbers are known to be in German format. Attempting to "detect" whether a string contains a German format or US format number is not arbitrary and out of scope for this question. `'1.234'` is valid in both formats but with different actual values, without context it is impossible to know for sure which format was meant.

```js
var numbers = ['1.000', '1,000', '1.000,89', '1.000.123.456,89'];

document.getElementById('out').value=numbers.map(function(str) {
  return parseFloat(str.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
}).join('\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="out" rows="10" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

Comment: Works fine! I extended it for up to two "cent" digits. ^-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{0,2})?$

Answer (score 3):

I would have posted this as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation.
@funkwurm, your post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28361329/7329611 contains javascript

```
var numbers = ['1.000', '1,000', '1.000,89', '1.000.123.456,89', '1.2'];
numbers.map(function(str) {
  return parseFloat(str.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
}).join('\n');
```

which should convert german numbers to english/international ones - which it does for every number with exactly three digits after a german thousands dot like the numbers you use in the example array. BUT - and there is the critical Use-Case-Error: it just deletes dots from any other string with not three digits after it aswell. 
So if you insert a string like '1.2' it returns 12, if you insert '1.23' it returns 123.
And this is a very critical behaviour, if anyone just takes the above code snippet and thinks it'll convert any given number correctly into english ones. Because **already correct english numbers will be corrupted**! So be careful, please.

Comment: I only now see this answer meant as a reply. By now you have the required reputation I see :) I've added a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work :

```
([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{3})*(?:\,[0-9]+)?)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good regex would be something like this

```
Regex regex = new Regex("-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?");
Match match = regex.Match(input);
Decimal result = Decimal.Zero;
if (match.Success)
     result = Decimal.Parse(match.Value, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

The result is the german number as parsed value.

Comment: So close, but `100.000` would not be validated when it should :)

Comment: You are right, I corrected a 2 to a 3, then it matches 3 digits before the dot

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will match your inputs:

```
^(\d+\.)*\d+(,\d+)?
```

Answer (score -1):

This regex would work for + numbers

```
/^[0-9]{0,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]{0,2})?$/
```

Breakdown

- `[0-9]{0,3}` - this section allows zero up to 3 numbers. empty value is valid, '1', '26', '789' are valid. '1589' is invalid
- `(\.[0-9]{3})*` - this section allows zero or more dots... if there's a dot, there must be three digits after the dot. '2.589' is valid. '2.5896' and '2.45' are invalid
- `(,[0-9]{0,2})?` - this section allows zero or 1 comma. there can be zero up to 2 digits after the comma. '25,', '25,5', '25,45' are valid. '25,456' and '25,45,8' are invalid

Hope this is helpful