# regex extraction with comma and thousand separators of various sizes

Tags: python, regex, string

I am working with a large string that looks something like this:

> ... amount 35.550,35 EUR ... something 7,2 EUR is ... costs 98.556.732,93 EUR ...

If someone could provide me with code to extract these numbers of various sizes using regex, I would be delighted.

I have tried something like this in python:

```
a.append(re.finditer(r"(\d+).EUR", str))
a.append(re.finditer(r"(\d+.\d+).EUR", str))
a.append(re.finditer(r"(\d+.\d+.\d+).EUR", str))
a.append(re.finditer(r"(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+).EUR", str))
```

but obviously this gives me lots of repetitions and is utterly clumsy.
Thank you!

Note: The postfix EUR is the only constant.

Comment: You may be facing an issue because `.` is a special regex character to mean any non-newline character, use `\.` to match '.'

Comment: See [this demo, for example](https://regex101.com/r/mXxWq9/1). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28361567/3832970) will work with `re.findall`

Comment: This works great, thank you for the quick aid!