# I cant create a regular expression for the spanish number format

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to transform this regex regular expression on c# to the spanish number format.

I want it to accept numbers with this format

Decimals with a comma and the thousands separator with a dot

```
10.000.000,262 <br>200,262<br>1.000.000
```

RegEx:

```
^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{10})?)
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28360966/1364007).

Comment: Does the string have `<br>` in it or are they actual line feeds?

Comment: Also, is your goal to simply convert these strings to numbers?

Comment: @DavidG OP never said something about conversion; he wants to write a Regex that matches this number format.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann I know what was said, but often people post [XY questions](http://xyproblem.info) where the ultimate goal is something else. In this case, I suspect they was the actual numbers which doesn't require a RegEx at all.

Comment: If you want to convert a string input to a Number, Parse and TryParse are the ways to go. Both have overloads that allow you to specify the culture. Usually the Thread/OS culture is used automagically, but it can be overridden. Even if you do not want this, it might be best to use data from the CultueFormat to make this Regex. You might also want to use the <br> or linefeeds to seperate the number into smaler strings in a preceeding step. Edit: Apparently doing Culture specific Regex falls into Localisation Mechanics, as you have to specify the regex string like a localized string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are after a very specific input format with a fixed number of allowed fraction digits. I think the pattern you want looks like this:

```
(\d{1,3}.?(\d{3}.?)*\d{3}(,\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(,\d{10})?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rhu2OA/1)

Answer (score 0):

To match decimals with a comma and the thousands separator with a dot you could use:

`\b\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?\b`

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\d{1,3}` Match a digit 1 - 3 times
- `(\.\d{3})*` match a dot and a 3 digits and repeat that zero or more times
- `(,\d+)?` Match a comma and one or more digits and make that optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%28%5c.%5cd%7b3%7d%29*%28%2c%5cd%2b%29%3f%5cb&i=10.000.000%2c262+%3cbr%3e200%2c262%3cbr%3e1.000.000)

Note that if you want to match a dot literally you should escape it `\.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a 1 to 3 number rule, it would be something like this

`(?<![\d.,])(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{1,3})?)(?![\d.,])`

Readable version

```
 (?<! [\d.,] )
 (?:
      \d{1,3} 
      (?:
           \.
           \d{3} 
      )*
      (?: , \d{1,3} )?
 )
 (?! [\d.,] )
```