# Find and extract a number which is in German digit format from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have some string containing numbers. The numbers are in german format (comma(,) instead of point (.)).
I want to get the numbers from the string.

`Regex.Match(test, @"\d+").Value;` doesn't work because of number format.

```
string test = "main(volatage1, voltage2, current)   0,017   0,77    v   100  I";
```

There is one tab space between each value. I managed to get the values using substring and IndexOf. But I doubt that it gonna fail if the numbers of digits are different. Any good way to get these numbers?

What I want is 
volatage1 = **0,017**   volatage2 = **0,77**  current = **100**.
Any suggestions.

Comment: It wouldn't work with ".", neither: https://regex101.com/r/PktiQw/1

Comment: This part: "main(volatage1, voltage2, current)" is it fix? Or do you have completely different inputs, too?

Comment: @Fildor Numbers should be similar in all cases. The number of digits vary.  but it won't work if there is no 0 before decimal point.

Comment: Yes, I am going somewhere. So do you _always_ have the prefix of "main(voltage1, voltage2, current)" and then the variable part with numbers?

Comment: @Fildor yes. That's right

Comment: Bingo. So my first step would be to cut that part off. Then you are left with "<tab><double><tab><double><tab>v<tab><int><tab>I" ... so, `current` should be easy to regex, since it is enclosed in "v<tab>" and "<tab>I". Then the remaining string should be easy to parse with split.

Comment: `\b[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]+)?\b` pattern

Comment: there is additional space after tab after 0,77

Comment: Not very elegant, but works also for ",77" and "1.234,56": https://dotnetfiddle.net/j7Fz7d

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
  using System.Linq;  
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string test =    
    @"main(volatage1, voltage2, current)   0,017   0,77    v   100  I";

  Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]+)?\b");

  double[] values = regex
    .Matches(test)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => double.Parse(match.Value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")))
    .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values));
```

**Outcome:**

```
0.017
0.77
100
```

**Pattern** `@"\b[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]+)?\b"` explained:

```
  \b         - word border (we don't want 1 in volatage1)
  [0-9]+     - mandatory integer part - one or more digits 0..9
  (?: ... )? - optional (? means zero or one) fraction part
  \,[0-9]+   -   which is comma followed by one or more digits 0..9
  \b         - word border
```

**Edit:** If we want to support *thousand separator* (`123.456.789,00`), values starting from *floating point separator* (`,123`),
*exponent* (`123,456e+23`) etc. we can either try to build a **huge** regular expression to match all these cases, e.g.

[Regular expression to match German number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360966/regular-expression-to-match-german-number)

or we can try to match a *possible* `double` value which then *check* with `TryParse`:

```
string test = 
  "main(volatage1, voltage2, current) 147.123,456  ,770 -,1234e+23   v   100  I";

// some mixture of digits, comma, dot, exp, pluses - possible number
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\-|\,|\b)[0-9\,\.eE\-\+]+\b");

double[] values = regex
  .Matches(test)
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => double.TryParse(match.Value, 
                                   NumberStyles.Any,
                                   CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), 
                                   out var v)
     ? v           // parsing succeeds 
     : double.NaN) // NaN - failed to parse
  .Where(item => !double.IsNaN(item))
  .ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values);
```

**Outcome:**

```
147123.456
0.77
-1.234E+22
100
```

Comment: What I don't like about the regex solutions here: They either don't work with ",77" or "1.234,56" ... If you could manage that, that would be awesome.

Comment: @Fildor: thank you for the intersting challenge! Even if it can be solved with regular epressions, the pattern will be huge and prone to errors. I suggest match good *candidates* for numbers which I can `TryParse` to check if they are real numbers or not

Comment: Brilliant, as always. Would upvote again, if I could.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression should capture all numbers:

`(\b\d+(,\d+)?)`

It states :

```
(         Start capture group
  \b      Word boundary, will prevent numbers within words, like voltage1 to be caught
  \d+     Matches 1 or more digits
  (       Start group
    ,     Matches a comma
    \d+   Matches 1 or more digits (these would be the decimals)
  )?      End optional group (the group is marked optional so we can match integers too
 )        End capture group
```

Edit: I initially read "I want to get the numbers from the string" and indeed caught *all* the numbers from the string. But by adding the word boundary `\b`, now the regex will only capture "standalone" numbers.

Comment: This also matches the "1" and "2" in "voltage1" and "voltage2" : https://regex101.com/r/sQ9F6s/1 , so yes. It captures **all** numbers :D (with an exception vv)

Comment: It wouldn't capture ",01"  instead it would only capture the "01"

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the numbers using this way:

```
    public static void ExtractNumbers()
    {
        string test = "main(volatage1, voltage2, current)   0,017   0,77    v   100  I";

        var tokens = test.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t'} );
        foreach (string s in tokens)
        {
            double d;
            Double.TryParse(s, out d);
        }
    }
```

/edit:

> Tested `TryParse`, works good, thanks!
>
> Tabs included

Comment: _"There is one **tab** space between each value"_

Comment: It would be better to use `double.TryParse` instead of catching exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression..

```
\d+,?\d+
```

To get all the matches using C#, try the following.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       string test = "main(volatage1, voltage2, current)   0,017   0,77    v   100  I";
       Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+,?\d+");


       foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(test)) {
           Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
       }
     }
}
```

You can check the code on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/87LONY)